# pandas merge multiple dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

For example: I have multiple dataframes. Each data frame has columns: variable_code, variable_description, year.

df1:

```
variable_code, variable_description 
N1, Number of returns     
N2, Number of Exemptions
```

df2:

```
variable_code, variable_description
N1,           Number of returns     
NUMDEP,         # of dependent
```

I want to merge these two dataframes to get all variable_codes in both df1 and df2.

```
variable_code, variable_description
N1             Number of returns
N2             Number of Exemption
NUMDEP         # of dependent
```

Comment: pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates() ?

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation for merge [right here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Since your columns you want to merge on are both called "variable_code" then you can use on='variable_code'

so the whole thing would be:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='variable_code')
```

You can specify How='outer' if you want blanks where you have data in only one of those tables.  Use how='inner' if you want only data that is in both tables (no blanks).

Comment: The columns that I want to merge is variable_code. If I do outer merge on variable_code, I will get columns: variable_code, variable_description_x, variable_description_y.

Comment: fixed, ty.  Yes you will.  There are 2 columns and since only the "on" column can have the same name between the 2 dataframes then '_x' will be added to all the overlapping column names on the left side (from df1) and df2 will get '_y'

Comment: Since "multiple dataframes" can also be 3, 4, etc, how can you handle it? Suppose there were 5 dataframes in this case.

Comment: @Gathide size will become a problem with too much data.  You will need to order the data in terms of dataframe size from smallest to largest.  (that might be over simplistic but helpful)  for x in [df2, df3, df4, df5]: df1= df1.merge(x, on='variable_code')     Hopefully your column names aren't the same in any of the data frames except for the "variable_code" column.  You might need to post up the question with constraints if that isn't the case.

Comment: @Back2Basics, Thanks for the follow-up. I got it. All columns with the same name should appear as a list under `on`, i.e. `on = ['varaible_code1','variable_code2', etc]`. The dataframes can also be in a list. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, concatenate df1, df2, by using

```
 final_df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).
```

Then we can convert columns variable_code, variable_name into dictionary. variable_code as keys, variable_name as values by using

```
 d = dict(zip(final_df['variable_code'], final_df['variable_name'])).
```

Then convert d into dataframe:

```
 d_df = pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()), columns=['variable_code', 'variable_name']).
```

Answer (score 0):

To attain your requirement, try this:

```
import pandas as pd

    #Create the first dataframe, through a dictionary - several other possibilities exist.
    data1 = {'variable_code': ['N1','N2'], 'variable_description': ['Number of returns','Number of Exemptions']}
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)

    #Create second  dataframe
    data2 = {'variable_code': ['N1','NUMDEP'], 'variable_description': ['Number of returns','# of dependent']}
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)

    #place the dataframes on a list. 
    dfs = [df1,df2] #additional dfs can be added here.
#You can loop over the list,merging the dfs. But here reduce and a lambda is used.
    resultant_df  = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['variable_code','variable_description'],how='outer'), dfs)
```

This gives:

```
>>> resultant_df
  variable_code  variable_description
0            N1     Number of returns
1            N2  Number of Exemptions
2        NUMDEP        # of dependent
```

There are several options available for `how`, each catering for various needs. `outer`, used here allows for inclusion of even the rows with empty data. See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for detailed explanation on the other options.